# Model not updated if a4j:ajax renders @form instead of other specific component

Tags: jsf, richfaces, jsf-2.2

In view I have this:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="makeSelect" value="#{bean.selectedMake}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="---" itemValue="#{null}" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.availableMakeList}"/>
    <a4j:ajax listener="#{bean.updateModelList}" render="@form"/>
    <h:messages/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

`bean.selectedMake` gets updated only on the first time I change the selection.
If I change `render="@form"` to `render="someOtherComponent"`, `bean.selectedMake` is updated normally. But I want to rerender all form.

Why model is not updated if I rerender all form?

Comment: any javascript errors on browser console?

Comment: No errors in console. No errors in h:messages.

Comment: looks like a specific component in your form cannot be re-rendered, causes a js error and that error blocks the next ajax request. however, that js error is not logged on console.